# Missing files in .ssh directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have updated my system with `sudo apt-get update`.
There was a update of PAM (The Pluggable Authentication Module). I don't remember the message, but there was like a pink screen and I decided to choose `no` (sorry for that poor explanation).

After that the update continues until something like `ssh stop/waiting` and then nothing happens. I couldn't cancel this und decided to reboot my Ubuntu Server (14.04 LTS).

After that I cannot connect with a user to this machine with `ssh -X user@host`. Only the owner can connect. But no other user.

With `ssh -v user@host` I get the error

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.`

Then I recognized that there are a lot of missing files in my `~/.ssh/` directory.

There is only the file `known_hosts`. I think there should be also the files: `Readme, authorized_keys, bup, deprec, id_dsa, id_dsa.pub`.

Do I have to reinstall ssh?

Comment: Due to the downvotes: How can I improve my question?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but I think you should ask this question on `askubuntu`, `serverfault` or `Unix&Linux` community

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reinstall `ssh`.

Many of those files are generate as you use `ssh` and related commands.

The most important files in my experience (which you will generate) are:

`authorized_keys`: contains public keys which are authorized to connect.

`id_dsa` and `id_dsa.pub` (or `id_rsa`, etc.) are the private key and public key (with `.pub` suffix) are the keys you offer when attempting a connection. These are generated by executing `ssh-keygen`.

Also, `config` is nice to use, but also not necessary. see [`man ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

## Restoring connections from other machines

It appears you've lost the `authorized_keys` file you had. If you wish to continue connecting via publickey from other machines, you will need to put the public key from the other machine into your `authorized_keys` file.

1. Ensure `authorized_keys` file exists (if not: `touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
2. Copy the public key (`id_rsa.pub` for example) from the machine[s] you will be connecting **from**.
3. Paste the public key[s] into `authorized_keys`, one per line.

Comment: Ok, thanks. With `ssh-keygen` I have create the files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. But I can't still connect with another user. Do I have to add them to the authorized_keys somehow?

Comment: @Stefan I added some info about restoring those connections.

Comment: @Stefan a note, if you're only interested in connecting *to* this maching, the `id_rsa` files serve no purpose and you can safely omit them. They're for outgoing connections. If you want to connect *to* this machine using public keys from *other* machines, you need to add them to `authorized_keys`.